# Fatal error in Calling woocommerce products

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I fix this error?
I started calling products through the Query, but I encountered this
I think the problem is with open and closed PHP tags, but I can not fix it

> Fatal error
>   : Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Product_Simple::have_posts() in C:\xampp\htdocs\gptec\fa\wp-content\themes\gptec_wptheme\index.php:102 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gptec\fa\wp-includes\template-loader.php(74): include() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\gptec\fa\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\gptec\fa\index.php(17): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gptec\fa\wp-content\themes\gptec_wptheme\index.php
>   on line
>   102

My codes  :

```
<div class="row">
<?php
$product=new WP_Query(
        array(
                'post_type'=>'product',
                 'post_per_page'=>6

        )
);



?>

<?php
    if ($product->have_posts())
    {
    while ($product->have_posts())
    $product->the_post();
    { ?>
    <div class="col-lg-3  p-2 m-2" >
        <div class="card card-4 text-center cls">
            <?php  the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <span class="description-text pb-1 mb-1"><?php  the_title()?></span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <a href="<?php  the_permalink() ?>">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success slideright p-2 m-2">مشاهده محصول</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php }}?>     <!--Card-->

</div>
```

Comment: That is because you opened php tag inside php tag

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile How can fix it ?

Comment: post your full code. I mean above args code in `$product->have_posts()`

Comment: @Vel ok check my code please

Comment: post your full code.

Comment: @Vel Please refresh the page i posted

Comment: no issue in your code. Its working fine for me. deactivate the woocommerce related plugin and check https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArWzT.png

Comment: or use some other variable name for this `$product`

Comment: Thank you, the problem was resolved  .The problem was the name of the variable
I changed it to the products and my problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

$product is global in woocommerce. So you are getting error.

So use some other variable instead of $product